# Why can't I tie a infinite rope in hard knots?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, knot-theory

I think this is a genuine math problem. And it's somehow related to [knot energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_energy) but not directly solved by the latter.

**Why can't I tie a hard knot on a rope of infinite length?**

By infinity I mean you never pull back either ends of the rope.

And I attentively add a constraint to the rope that the rope is smooth thus no friction. So the problem is only about the topology (not exactly) of that rope.

I cannot think of a better word than topology since the topology of the rope should never change. But apparently I don't know a better one.

In my preliminary thoughts, there should be a solution that performs a integration involving the direction and twist of the rope along the infinite length. And the sign of the integration determines whether it's a hard knot or not. And the fact that you cannot pull back the end means you cannot change that sign.

Comment: What is a "hard" knot here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Intuitively it's a knot that cannot be removed by pulling from both ends.

Comment: x @Soless: What are the rules for how the rope responds to pulling? Does it have finite thickness in addition to being frictionless? Does "being tied" on an infinite rope imply that the knot must be homotopic to an infinite straight rope?

Comment: You cannot tie a knot for the same reason you cannot tie a knot in a rope secured to  walls at both ends, and you cannot start with the unknot in $\mathbb S^3$ or $\mathbb R^3$ and create a knot.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I know an infinite rope equals a rope tied to walls. However I'm looking for a more mathematical explanation. Could you elaborate more on your latter part? The $\mathcal{R}^3$ part plz.

Comment: I can recommend books for beginners by Adams, Crowell, and Livingston,  http://www.abebooks.com/Knot-Book-Elementary-Introduction-Mathematical-Theory/11970803931/bd?cm_mmc=gmc-_-gmc-_-PLA-_-v01   and http://www.abebooks.com/products/isbn/9780486468945?cm_sp=rec-_-bdp-_-plp  and http://www.abebooks.com/products/isbn/9780883850275?cm_sp=rec-_-plp-_-plp

Comment: @Will: *"you cannot start with the unknot ... and create a knot"* - no matter what the ambient space or context, isn't this essentially a tautology? "Create" means "transform by isotopies", and isotopies are invertible by "running time backwards". Anything you can create from a given knot must in turn be able to create the original, so anything created from an unknot is also an unknot.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, yes. i think the best thing for this OP is some books for beginners. I think he is an undergraduate in China, but seems comfortable with English.

Comment: @Will: Heh, I just realized I made an inadvertent rope pun - ***taut*** ology... $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ZevChonoles, very good

Comment: @ZevChonoles glad to hear you think I'm comfortable with English. Actually I came cross this question in a Chinese version of `Quora.com`, where I came up with a similar solution using `inverted isotopies`. And I find out that the key to the solution is how you define a 'knot'.

Comment: This is closely related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660580) from a few days ago. You might find the answers there useful.

Comment: Not being a mathematician, and bringing up a zombie, I wonder if the premise is even sound.  Infinity is really odd stuff.  Doesn't the response really depend upon what sort of space the rope is placed in? I would have thought that using some non-euclidean spaces would trivially allow for a rope to be tied - even merely a spherical space where the infinite rope is a loop, it's pretty trivial to tie a non-slipknot (ie the OP 'hard knot').